# Unity 5.6.3 Failed to re-package resources

Tags: c#, android, facebook, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

I have searched far and wide for a solution. Unity is failing to re-package resources when building for android.

I have downgraded tools to 25.2.5. I upgraded to the latest Unity 5.6.3. I am using the latest Facebook for Unity SDK. I have upgraded and downgraded the majority of my sdk folders to no avail. Ive been searching for a solution all day. Can you make any sense out of this console log?

```
    CommandInvokationFailure: Failed to re-package resources.
C:\Users\Trent\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\24.0.3\aapt.exe package --auto-add-overlay -v -f -m -J "gen" -M "AndroidManifest.xml" -S "res" -I "C:/Users/Trent/AppData/Local/Android/sdk\platforms\android-25\android.jar" -F bin/resources.ap_ --extra-packages android.support.graphics.drawable.animated:android.support.v7.appcompat:android.support.v7.cardview:android.support.customtabs:com.facebook:com.facebook:com.facebook.android:com.facebook.android:android.support.v4:android.support.graphics.drawable -S "C:\Users\Trent\Documents\Jumpr\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\animated-vector-drawable-23.4.0\res" -S "C:\Users\Trent\Documents\Jumpr\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.4.0\res" -S "C:\Users\Trent\Documents\Jumpr\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\cardview-v7-23.4.0\res" -S "C:\Users\Trent\Documents\Jumpr\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\customtabs-23.4.0\res" -S "C:\Users\Trent\Documents\Jumpr\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\facebook-android-sdk-4.17.0\res" -S "C:\Users\Trent\Documents\Jumpr\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\facebook-android-sdk-4.7.0\res" -S "C:\Users\Trent\Documents\Jumpr\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\facebook-android-wrapper-7.9.4\res" -S "C:\Users\Trent\Documents\Jumpr\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\facebook-android-wrapper-release\res" -S "C:\Users\Trent\Documents\Jumpr\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\support-v4-23.4.0\res" -S "C:\Users\Trent\Documents\Jumpr\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\support-vector-drawable-23.4.0\res"

stderr[
C:\Users\Trent\Documents\Jumpr\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.4.0\res\layout\abc_alert_dialog_button_bar_material.xml:18: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layoutDirection from <android.support.v7.widget.ButtonBarLayout>
C:\Users\Trent\Documents\Jumpr\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.4.0\res\layout\abc_alert_dialog_button_bar_material.xml: note: using v17 attributes; synthesizing resource com.trentpierce.jumpr:layout/abc_alert_dialog_button_bar_material for configuration v17.
C:\Users\Trent\Documents\Jumpr\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.4.0\res\layout\abc_alert_dialog_material.xml:48: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:textAlignment from <android.support.v7.widget.DialogTitle>
C:\Users\Trent\Documents\Jumpr\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.4.0\res\layout\abc_alert_dialog_material.xml: note: using v17 attributes; synthesizing resource com.trentpierce.jumpr:layout/abc_alert_dialog_material for configuration v17.
C:\Users\Trent\Documents\Jumpr\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.4.0\res\layout\abc_dialog_title_material.xml:29: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:textAlignment from <TextView>
C:\Users\Trent\Documents\Jumpr\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.4.0\res\layout\abc_dialog_title_material.xml: note: using v17 attributes; synthesizing resource com.trentpierce.jumpr:layout/abc_dialog_title_material for configuration v17.
C:\Users\Trent\Documents\Jumpr\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.4.0\res\layout\abc_screen_toolbar.xml:27: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:touchscreenBlocksFocus from <android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarContainer>
C:\Users\Trent\Documents\Jumpr\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.4.0\res\layout\abc_screen_toolbar.xml: note: using v21 attributes; synthesizing resource com.trentpierce.jumpr:layout/abc_screen_toolbar for configuration v21.
C:\Users\Trent\Documents\Jumpr\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.4.0\res\layout\abc_search_view.xml:47: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layoutDirection from <LinearLayout>
C:\Users\Trent\Documents\Jumpr\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.4.0\res\layout\abc_search_view.xml: note: using v17 attributes; synthesizing resource com.trentpierce.jumpr:layout/abc_search_view for configuration v17.
C:\Users\Trent\Documents\Jumpr\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\facebook-android-sdk-4.17.0\res\layout\com_facebook_device_auth_dialog_fragment.xml:80: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layout_marginEnd from <TextView>
C:\Users\Trent\Documents\Jumpr\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\facebook-android-sdk-4.17.0\res\layout\com_facebook_device_auth_dialog_fragment.xml:80: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layout_marginStart from <TextView>
C:\Users\Trent\Documents\Jumpr\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\facebook-android-sdk-4.17.0\res\layout\com_facebook_device_auth_dialog_fragment.xml: note: using v17 attributes; synthesizing resource com.trentpierce.jumpr:layout/com_facebook_device_auth_dialog_fragment for configuration v17.
C:\Users\Trent\Documents\Jumpr\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\facebook-android-sdk-4.17.0\res\layout\com_facebook_smart_device_dialog_fragment.xml:112: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layout_marginStart from <TextView>
C:\Users\Trent\Documents\Jumpr\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\facebook-android-sdk-4.17.0\res\layout\com_facebook_smart_device_dialog_fragment.xml:112: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layout_marginEnd from <TextView>
C:\Users\Trent\Documents\Jumpr\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\facebook-android-sdk-4.17.0\res\layout\com_facebook_smart_device_dialog_fragment.xml:47: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layout_marginStart from <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView>
C:\Users\Trent\Documents\Jumpr\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\facebook-android-sdk-4.17.0\res\layout\com_facebook_smart_device_dialog_fragment.xml: note: using v17 attributes; synthesizing resource com.trentpierce.jumpr:layout/com_facebook_smart_device_dialog_fragment for configuration v17.
C:\Users\Trent\Documents\Jumpr\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.4.0\res\layout\notification_template_big_media.xml:42: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layoutDirection from <LinearLayout>
C:\Users\Trent\Documents\Jumpr\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.4.0\res\layout\notification_template_big_media.xml:34: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layout_marginStart from <include>
C:\Users\Trent\Documents\Jumpr\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.4.0\res\layout\notification_template_big_media.xml:34: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layout_toStartOf from <include>
C:\Users\Trent\Documents\Jumpr\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.4.0\res\layout\notification_template_big_media.xml: note: using v17 attributes; synthesizing resource com.trentpierce.jumpr:layout/notification_template_big_media for configuration v17.
C:\Users\Trent\Documents\Jumpr\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.4.0\res\layout\notification_template_big_media_narrow.xml:60: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layout_toEndOf from <ImageView>
C:\Users\Trent\Documents\Jumpr\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.4.0\res\layout\notification_template_big_media_narrow.xml:46: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layout_toEndOf from <LinearLayout>
C:\Users\Trent\Documents\Jumpr\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.4.0\res\layout\notification_template_big_media_narrow.xml:46: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layoutDirection from <LinearLayout>
C:\Users\Trent\Documents\Jumpr\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.4.0\res\layout\notification_template_big_media_narrow.xml:38: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layout_marginStart from <include>
C:\Users\Trent\Documents\Jumpr\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.4.0\res\layout\notification_template_big_media_narrow.xml:38: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layout_toStartOf from <include>
C:\Users\Trent\Documents\Jumpr\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.4.0\res\layout\notification_template_big_media_narrow.xml:30: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layout_alignParentEnd from <include>
C:\Users\Trent\Documents\Jumpr\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.4.0\res\layout\notification_template_big_media_narrow.xml: note: using v17 attributes; synthesizing resource com.trentpierce.jumpr:layout/notification_template_big_media_narrow for configuration v17.
C:\Users\Trent\Documents\Jumpr\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.4.0\res\layout\notification_template_lines.xml:18: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:paddingEnd from <LinearLayout>
C:\Users\Trent\Documents\Jumpr\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.4.0\res\layout\notification_template_lines.xml:77: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layout_marginStart from <LinearLayout>
C:\Users\Trent\Documents\Jumpr\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.4.0\res\layout\notification_template_lines.xml:96: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:paddingStart from <TextView>
C:\Users\Trent\Documents\Jumpr\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.4.0\res\layout\notification_template_lines.xml:64: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layout_marginStart from <TextView>
C:\Users\Trent\Documents\Jumpr\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.4.0\res\layout\notification_template_lines.xml:27: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layout_marginStart from <LinearLayout>
C:\Users\Trent\Documents\Jumpr\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.4.0\res\layout\notification_template_lines.xml: note: using v17 attributes; synthesizing resource com.trentpierce.jumpr:layout/notification_template_lines for configuration v17.
C:\Users\Trent\Documents\Jumpr\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.4.0\res\layout\notification_template_media.xml:43: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layout_marginEnd from <include>
C:\Users\Trent\Documents\Jumpr\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.4.0\res\layout\notification_template_media.xml:33: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layoutDirection from <LinearLayout>
C:\Users\Trent\Documents\Jumpr\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.4.0\res\layout\notification_template_media.xml: note: using v17 attributes; synthesizing resource com.trentpierce.jumpr:layout/notification_template_media for configuration v17.
C:\Users\Trent\Documents\Jumpr\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.4.0\res\layout\notification_template_part_chronometer.xml:18: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:paddingStart from <Chronometer>
C:\Users\Trent\Documents\Jumpr\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.4.0\res\layout\notification_template_part_chronometer.xml: note: using v17 attributes; synthesizing resource com.trentpierce.jumpr:layout/notification_template_part_chronometer for configuration v17.
C:\Users\Trent\Documents\Jumpr\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.4.0\res\layout\notification_template_part_time.xml:18: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:paddingStart from <DateTimeView>
C:\Users\Trent\Documents\Jumpr\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.4.0\res\layout\notification_template_part_time.xml: note: using v17 attributes; synthesizing resource com.trentpierce.jumpr:layout/notification_template_part_time for configuration v17.
C:\Users\Trent\Documents\Jumpr\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.4.0\res\layout\select_dialog_multichoice_material.xml:18: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:paddingStart from <CheckedTextView>
C:\Users\Trent\Documents\Jumpr\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.4.0\res\layout\select_dialog_multichoice_material.xml:18: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:paddingEnd from <CheckedTextView>
C:\Users\Trent\Documents\Jumpr\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.4.0\res\layout\select_dialog_multichoice_material.xml: note: using v17 attributes; synthesizing resource com.trentpierce.jumpr:layout/select_dialog_multichoice_material for configuration v17.
C:\Users\Trent\Documents\Jumpr\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.4.0\res\layout\select_dialog_singlechoice_material.xml:18: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:paddingStart from <CheckedTextView>
C:\Users\Trent\Documents\Jumpr\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.4.0\res\layout\select_dialog_singlechoice_material.xml:18: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:paddingEnd from <CheckedTextView>
C:\Users\Trent\Documents\Jumpr\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.4.0\res\layout\select_dialog_singlechoice_material.xml: note: using v17 attributes; synthesizing resource com.trentpierce.jumpr:layout/select_dialog_singlechoice_material for configuration v17.
C:\Users\Trent\Documents\Jumpr\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.4.0\res\drawable\abc_ratingbar_indicator_material.xml:23: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:tileModeX from <bitmap>
C:\Users\Trent\Documents\Jumpr\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.4.0\res\drawable\abc_ratingbar_indicator_material.xml: note: using v21 attributes; synthesizing resource com.trentpierce.jumpr:drawable/abc_ratingbar_indicator_material for configuration v21.
C:\Users\Trent\Documents\Jumpr\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.4.0\res\drawable\abc_ratingbar_small_material.xml:23: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:tileModeX from <bitmap>
C:\Users\Trent\Documents\Jumpr\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.4.0\res\drawable\abc_ratingbar_small_material.xml: note: using v21 attributes; synthesizing resource com.trentpierce.jumpr:drawable/abc_ratingbar_small_material for configuration v21.
C:\Users\Trent\Documents\Jumpr\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\facebook-android-sdk-4.17.0\res\drawable\com_facebook_favicon_blue.xml:21: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:viewportHeight from <vector>
C:\Users\Trent\Documents\Jumpr\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\facebook-android-sdk-4.17.0\res\drawable\com_facebook_favicon_blue.xml:21: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:viewportWidth from <vector>
C:\Users\Trent\Documents\Jumpr\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\facebook-android-sdk-4.17.0\res\drawable\com_facebook_favicon_blue.xml:26: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:fillColor from <path>
C:\Users\Trent\Documents\Jumpr\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\facebook-android-sdk-4.17.0\res\drawable\com_facebook_favicon_blue.xml:26: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:pathData from <path>
C:\Users\Trent\Documents\Jumpr\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\facebook-android-sdk-4.17.0\res\drawable\com_facebook_favicon_blue.xml: note: using v21 attributes; synthesizing resource com.trentpierce.jumpr:drawable/com_facebook_favicon_blue for configuration v21.
C:\Users\Trent\Documents\Jumpr\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\facebook-android-sdk-4.17.0\res\values\values.xml:22: error: Attribute "com_facebook_object_type" already defined with incompatible format.
C:\Users\Trent\Documents\Jumpr\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\facebook-android-sdk-4.7.0\res\values\values.xml:18: Original attribute defined here.
C:\Users\Trent\Documents\Jumpr\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\facebook-android-sdk-4.17.0\res\values\values.xml:22: error: Attribute "com_facebook_style" already defined with incompatible format.
C:\Users\Trent\Documents\Jumpr\Temp\StagingArea\<message truncated>
```

Comment: are you building using a keystore?

Comment: Ive tried both with and without a keystore. I even tried building with gradle using a keystore. I then exported the project to android studio and tried building there, but it threw an error on the facebook sdk.

Comment: I was having packing issue because I copied my keystore which messed everything up!

Comment: Did you try the solutions here : [Failed to re-package resources](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/760989/failed-to-re-package-resources-2.html)

Comment: I went ahead and downgraded my build-tools to 23.0.2, and it still fails. Ive searched every possible manifest file in the project folder, and I cant find a single reference to google play services.